# Taking a linear operator inside an integral

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods

I am currently reading up on the Newton iteration, and have come across a step in a proof that I don't understand, and am having difficulty finding in a numerical analysis textbook (as I don't know if it has a specific name).

I think I need an inequality that states

$A\int_{\Omega}B(x) \text{d}x \geq \int_{\Omega}AB(x) \text{d}x$

For $B$ a generic operator, and $A$ a linear operator on a convex domain $D$. Is anyone aware of a theorem like this?

If there isn't a general theorem of the above form I am including more detailed information about the specific instance with which I am having difficulties below.

I start with a nonlinear system

$F(x) = 0$

It is assumed that $F: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is continuously Frechet differentiable on convex domain $D$, and that the inverse of the derivative $F'(x)$ exists for $x \in D$.

The Newton iteration is written as

$x^{k+1} = x^{k} + \Delta x^{k}$

where $\Delta x^{k} = -F'(x^{k})^{-1}F(x^{k})$.

Now we take two Newton sequences $\{x^{k}\}$ and $\{y^{k}\}$ starting from $x^{0}$ and $y^{0}$. Using the above definitions it can be shown that

$x^{k+1} - y^{k+1} = x^{k} + \Delta x^{k} - y^{k} - \Delta y^{k} \\ = F'(x^{k})^{-1}\left( F'(x^{k})(x^{k} - y^{k}) - \int_{0}^{1}F'(y^{k} + t(x^{k}-y^{k}))(x^{k}-y^{k})\text{d}t \right) + \\ \quad \quad F'(x^{k})^{-1}(F'(y^{k}) - F'(x^{k}))\Delta{y}^{k}.$

From this point the next step in the book is to state that

$||x^{k+1} - y^{k+1}|| \leq \int_{t=0}^{1}||F'(x^{k})^{-1}\left( F'(x^{k}) - F'(y^{k} + t(x^{k} - y^{k})) \right) (x^{k} - y^{k}) \text{d}t|| + \\ \quad \quad \quad ||F'(x^{k})^{-1}(F'(y^{k}) - F'(x^{k}))\Delta y^{k}||$,

which is where I get lost. I get the use of the triangle inequality, and I know that $||\int_{\Omega}x|| \leq \int_{\Omega}||x||$, but I haven't come accross anything that would allow me to take the linear operator $F'(x^{k})^{-1}$ inside the integral sign, such that (as far as I can tell) I would need an inequality of the form

$F'(x^{k})^{-1}\int_{\Omega}G(x^{k})\text{d}x \geq \int_{\Omega}F'(x^{k})^{-1}G(x)\text{d}t$

for the previous inequality to hold. Is this correct? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Cheers,
Keeran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you have to use is just the fact that integration is linear.
By looking at the $i$th coordinate you get

$\begin{align} \left(A \int f(x) dx\right)_i 
&= \sum_{j} A_{i,j} \left(\int f(x) dx\right)_j\\
&= \sum_{j} A_{i,j} \int f(x)_j dx\\ 
&= \int \sum_{j} A_{i,j}f(x)_j dx\\ 
&= \int (A f(x))_i dx \\
&= \left(\int A f(x) dx \right)_i
\end{align}$

and this gives you $A \int f(x) dx = \int A f(x) dx$.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. What happens if $F$ no longer acts on a finite dimensional space? Is it possible to state the same result using limits? I.e. if $A: X \rightarrow Y$ is a bounded linear operator on Hilbert spaces $X$ and $Y$ can we define a finite dimensional hierarchy $X_{1} \subset X_{2} \subset \ldots $ such that $\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}X_{i} = X$ and hence use the above argument, along with boundedness of the operator $A$ to say that this works in the infinite dimensional case, or is this too large a jump?

Comment: I am an not an expert in this field but I suppose the main problem is to make the integral a useful concept. I do not know if there is something as canonical as "integrating every component" in this case. Also note that even if your limit approach works it would only cover the case of Hilbert spaces having a countable basis.